# Add custom legend values for complexheatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, complexheatmap

I am setting the legend values manually, but still the heat map produces different min median and max values as seen in the image. Any idea why my custom values are not shown and used by the legend?

```
col_fun = colorRamp2(c(-11,-5,2), c("blue", "white", "red"))

Heatmap <- Heatmap(t(as.matrix(df)),
                             name="Abundance (log2)",
                             left_annotation = ha,
                             show_column_dend = FALSE,
                             show_row_dend = FALSE, #row_order  = c(2,1),
                             column_names_gp = grid::gpar(fontsize = 8),
                             row_names_gp = grid::gpar(fontsize = 8),
                            col=col_fun,
                             heatmap_legend_param = list(
                               title = "Abundance (log2)",
                               legend_height = unit(1.5, "cm"),
                               title_position = "topcenter",
                               title_gp = gpar(fontsize = 6),
                               labels_gp = gpar(fontsize = 6),
                               direction = "horizontal"
                               , labels_rot = 0)
)
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide some (made-up) data (for `df`) so the example is reproducible. Thank you!

Comment: Does this work? `Heatmap(t(as.matrix(df)), heatmap_legend_param = list(at = c(-11,-5,2)))`. You have only defined the range for the color-function if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: yes, but defining them like Min=-3, Med=0, Max=5  and then: c(Min,Med,Max) does not work.Ideas?

Comment: It is unclear to me what exactly isn't working for you. Can you please provide a reproducible example? If I define the variables `Min` , `Med` and `Max` and insert them both into the `colorRamp2()` function and into the `heatmap_legend_param` then everything looks fine to me.